# Issue installing puppet on centos 6.5

Tags: puppet, centos6

Previously I had been installing puppet on my centos 6.5 instances with the following code

```
# Install & configure puppet 
rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
yum -y install puppet
```

I am now getting the following error:

```
Retrieving http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: skipping http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm - transfer failed
```

I check the URL, and indeed this file does not appear to be there anymore. Has puppet dropped their support for centos 6.5? I'm running version 3.X of puppet, and I don't think the code will run on later versions.

Comment: FYI, it looks like the URL is now again active. This must have been just a glitch in the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original URL that I was using was later restored.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that Puppet renamed themselves from Puppetlabs some years ago. They propagated this name change into their code as well. You need to update the rpm retrieval to: http://yum.puppet.com/puppet-release-el-6.noarch.rpm.

```
rpm -ivh http://yum.puppet.com/puppet-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: Or, to be a bit more forward looking, use `http://yum.puppet.com/puppet-release-el-6.noarch.rpm`, and update your docs to specify that.  Puppet, Inc. might eventually drop the puppetlabs.com domain.

Comment: I ran the same command within the last week and it ran successfully. The old yum URL would install version 3.8.7. Ah, nevermind... as I write this response... it looks like the old URL is now active again. I can take my tinfoil hat off now... all is well :)